# IndexError at /searchbar/

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to get slug attribute from my model.

```
  if request.method == 'GET':
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        stocksearch = Stock.objects.filter(slug=search)
        var = stocksearch[0].slug
        print(var)
        if stocksearch:
            return render(request, 'stocks/searchbar.html', {'stocksearch': stocksearch})
        else:
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0'}
            ticker = var
            prntvar = {'prntnum': 0}
            mydef = mydefinations()
```

In line 3

> stocksearch = Stock.objects.filter(slug=search)

In this line i get a queryset.

Then in line 4, i got the slug from stocksearch. if the condition is true then it prints slug in the console and in case of ELSE it give me error

> IndexError at /searchbar/

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    ext = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
```

This is my model and i only want to get slug value of filtered stock

Answer (score 1):

Actually i was trying to find slug item, which i searched. But later I found this solution and slug will be in search variable. It solved my problem.

> search = request.GET.get('search')

Sometime, a little thing gets out of your head. Thanks to all.